# Error UIScrollView in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I have a view that is composed of an image, a form with 11 UITextfield and a button, but the form is too big for my screen that is why I tried to use a UIScrollview.

The error I have is that my UIScrollview does not work as I can solve this problem.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class LoginCtrl: UIViewController {
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        sv.isScrollEnabled = true
        sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 5678)
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sv
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 0, g: 150, b: 136)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contenedorCampos)
        setear_posicion_scrollView()
        setear_posicion_contenedor()
    }
    func setear_posicion_scrollView(){
        //definir x,y,width,height constraints
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    var heightContenedor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    func setear_posicion_contenedor(){
        //definir x,y,width,height constraints
        contenedorCampos.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contenedorCampos.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabsInicio.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        contenedorCampos.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        heightContenedor = contenedorCampos.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)
        heightContenedor?.isActive = true

        contenedorCampos.addSubview(txtNombres)
        contenedorCampos.addSubview(divider_txtNombres)....
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How can I do,  I'm new in this

Comment: What does "my UIScrollview does not work" even mean? What's your question? Also please show your real code, not excerpts.

Comment: it means that my content is allways static, I will copy all my code

Comment: @matt I edited my question

Comment: "it means that my content is allways static" That means that your scroll view's `contentSize` is not larger than your scroll view's size. Use logging to demonstrate that fact to yourself

Comment: @matt sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 5678) I have this, is it correct?

Comment: But perhaps that is not what it ends up at. Use logging, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the relationship between the scrollview and its superview(which defines its `frame`), but not the relationship between the scrollview and its subviews (which defines its `contentSize`). As a result, the actual `contentSize` of the scrollview will be just be `(0, 0)`.

In other words, you never actually laid anything out, at least not in the code you posted.

What you need to do is define layout constraints for the actual child views (everything that is a subview of the scrollview). Make sure to set up constraints definitively pinning these components to the edges of their parent (the scrollview). Once you have defined the constraints sufficiently, the scrollview should have a content size.

[Technical note about this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

> In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right
>   edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to
>   the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the
>   minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin
>   of the superview does not change the position of the view.
>
> The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of
>   its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom,
>   and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content
>   view.
>
> The constraints on the subviews of the scroll view must result in a
>   size to fill, which is then interpreted as the content size of the
>   scroll view. (This should not be confused with the
>   intrinsicContentSize method used for Auto Layout.) To size the scroll
>   view’s frame with Auto Layout, constraints must either be explicit
>   regarding the width and height of the scroll view, or the edges of the
>   scroll view must be tied to views outside of its subtree.